# Listing a filter object twice will return a blank list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I'm using the filter function in Python (3.3). I tried to convert the filter object to list. That's what I found:

```
>>> a=['1', '2', '3', None]
>>> b=filter(None,a)
>>> list(b)
['1', '2', '3']
>>> list(b)
[]
```

That's quite strange to me. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 13):

In Python 3, [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) returns an [*iterator type*](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), and like all iterators, can only be iterated over just once. The `filter()` iterator filters values on demand, it doesn't hold any filtered values in memory itself.

You can do the same with the list iterator, returned by `iter()`:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = iter(a)
>>> list(b)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list(b)
[]
```

This happens because the [`.__next__()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator.__next__) of iterators are expected to raise `StopIteration` once exhausted, then must *always* raise `StopIteration` from there on out:

> Once an iterator’s `__next__()` method raises `StopIteration`, it must continue to do so on subsequent calls. Implementations that do not obey this property are deemed broken.

`filter()` does this correctly:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, None]
>>> b = filter(None, a)
>>> list(b)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> next(b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Here the [`next()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) calls the `.__next__()` iterator method, and propagates the exception raised; `list()` on the other hand iterates until `StopIteration`, catches that exception and returns a list of whatever elements it managed to receive.

For completeness sake, in Python 2, `filter()` (as well as many other built-in functions and methods) returns a `list`, often wasting memory and cycles on building an intermediary list object that was then discarded again after iteration. By returning an iterator instead, the choice to materialize a list is up to the programmer instead.